# R - create a ROC curve with binary predictions

Tags: r, data-visualization, roc

I have situations that can be "normal" or "problematic". I have an algorithm that is supposed to detect when a situation is problematic as fast as possible using situations' characteristics (so binary predictions, no continuous probability). I want to evaluate the "as fast as possible": when reducing (regarding time) the data available to a shorter and shorter window, does the algorithm conserves approximately its performance or is there a significant drop? When the window becomes shorter and shorter, are most of situations misclassified or not?

I used a loop to compute the algorithm performances using a window of 1s, 10s, 20s etc. For each window, I compare the 'truth' of each situation to the output of the algorithm using only the data available in the given window. Using the `caret` package I computed the sensitivity and specificity. So far so good.

But I wanted to use a ROC curve, as it is convenient to illustrate algorithms' performances. However, I am struggling to understand the concept. I firstly used a script of my own in R, which creates the points on a ROC graph. But I would like to have something similar to a ROC curve with vertical/horizontal lines linking the points. I tried to use the package `ROCR` to plot a ROC curve, however I don't know how to make it understand that I have a variable (the length of the window).

At this point I don't know if 1/ I understood the concept of ROC curve (can I use it for binary predictions) and 2/ can I do it with the ROCR package? (and 3/ if not, how ?).

Comment: I don't know about ROCR, but if you already computed the sensitivity and specificity you can just plot them, using base: `plot(1-specificity, sensitivity, type = "l")` or ggplot2: `ggplot(data_frame) + geom_line(aes(x=1-specificity, y=sensitivity))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you say yes, I can plot with points and lines, and I did. However from what I saw ROC curves only display vertical and horizontal lines (them being only perpendicular to each other, like small steps), and I would like to have the same. Unfortunately with `geom_line` the lines are direct from point to point, and so can be diagonals. Or is there an option to do it?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood the problem. You can try with `geom_step()`, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Or at least I only have to plot manually the last line between last point and top right corner. For some unknown it does not work with `ggplotly`, but still I have approximately what I wanted through `geom_step`, even though I still don't understand ROCR ><